# Web API Security using Individual User Accounts and Custom Storage Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a REST based application using Web Api 2.  On the project, I elected to use the individual user accounts option when I created my project.  On the frontend, I am using a combination of angularjs and ios interfaces to interact with web api.  I would like a user to enter their credentials and upon successful authentication, receive a jwt token(SSL) that they can use as long as the ticket hasn't expired.  I read an article outlining how to create a custom storage provider, which I need as my user schema is different from asp.net identity.

What is the recommended approach to this scenario?

Can someone provide an example of how to setup .net individual accounts for authenticating users trying to access web api action methods?  As stated above, the user interface is angularjs.

Comment: I think you'll need to narrow down your questions, as at the moment your question is too broad or has too many questions

Comment: Maybe you can just add a mapping table which maps user-ids from different security providers to your internal representation... We did this for one of our applications after enabling facebook and active directory logins for existing users...

Comment: If you are OK upgrading to .Net Core, you can use this guide: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-resource-owner-dalvandi?trk=mp-author-card